# Sending 200 success using node js Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, functions-framework

I'm trying to send a 200 - Success back using the 'res' parameter of a google cloud function. I kept getting the error '*TypeError: res.setStatusCode is not a function.*' even though this should be a part of the object. So I did the below to make sure.

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

functions.cloudEvent('app', (req, res) => {
    
    console.log(typeof res); // "Function"
    console.log(Object.keys(res)); // []
    console.log(res.statusCode); // undefined
    console.log(res.headers); // undefined
    console.log(res.body); // undefined
    
    res.setStatusCode(400);
    res.send('Success');
    
});
```

It appears res is actually a function (not an object) and statusCode is not defined. Is this correct or Am I missing something here? How do I change this to send a 200 while using @google-cloud/functions-framework? Thank you.

Comment: idk anything about this but i searched on [github](https://github.com/search?q=functions.cloudEvent+language%3AJavaScript&type=code&l=JavaScript) and [this](https://github.com/OpenFunction/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/edb1a97868b628054c49ba0ec48e0603bcbc0887/test/conformance/function.js#L14) does `functions.http` to get access to req and res

Comment: @cmgchess yeah, that library is really poorly documented but from what I can see in the types, those are different exports for different purposes

Comment: Yeah. I managed to get this done with functions.http. I'll update an example answer. Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cmgchess suggested, this was achieved by using `functions.http`. I'm adding an example code block for anyone who may get the same problem.

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

functions.http('app', (req, res) => {
   //Do your work
   res.status(200).send('Success');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`functions-framework` is built on top of Express, and their req/res objects wrap Express's, so it should be `res.status`, not `res.setStatusCode`.

Additionally, you're mixing the cloudEvent API with the http API. If you want to directly work with the request and response objects, it looks like you'll need to use [cloudevents](https://github.com/cloudevents/sdk-javascript) — I'm unable to find anything in the `functions-framework` repo that points to a better option, but I would welcome a correction on that.

Also there's no need to manually set a 200, because that's the default.

Comment: Thanks, Zac, It still gives an error, 'TypeError: res.status is not a function' (or 'TypeError: res.send is not a function'). I think this is due to res being a function. That is where I'm actually stuck.

Comment: Oh of course, I see, let me update my answer

Comment: Thanks again Zac. Same with me. I also can't find anything in the functions-framework to achieve this. Will update here if I get an answer.